# Fullcalendar : what format does event's 'start' property expect

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

So I started to use fullcalendar and slowly made progress on how to manipulate events. However, I do not quite under stand how 'start' should be set when initializing an event. So usually I write code like this

```
    var event_data = {
        title: "this is title",
        start: new Date(y,m,d+2, 8)
    }
    calendar.addEvent(event_data, true);
```

where `y=new Date().getFullYear()` and so on.

Now I want to initialize an event_data similar to above, but the only information I know is that it happens on **this Tuesday (not the following Tuesday)** and it starts on **14:00**. How should I initialize start time in this case? In addition, maybe someone could explain how to use moment to populate 'start' property?

Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can just set it in your start date, as:

```
var event_data = {
    title: "this is title",
    start: new Date(y,m,d+2, 14, 0, 0)
}
calendar.addEvent(event_data, true);
```

js [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) allows parameters as `Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]]);`